# Does starting a server at localhost:8081 creates internet connection issues?

Tags: node.js, http, webserver, localhost, webservice-client

I have started a server at local host:8081 as

```
var http = require("http");  
http.createServer(function (request, response) {  
 // Send the HTTP header   
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK  
   // Content Type: text/plain  
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});  
   // Send the response body as "Hello World"  
   response.end('Hello World\n');  
}).listen(8081);  
// Console will print the message  
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

After starting the service, I am not able to access internet. please help me with this.

Comment: Just tested your code and it worked fine, as well as the internet. After starting it, can you at least ping a random website? What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: I am using windows7 and a crhrome browser

Comment: Does ping to a webpage work? Does the internet work in some other browser - IE, Edge, FF?